# How can I convert already recorded speech to text?

Tags: software-rec, audio, speech-to-text

I am looking for a software that would allow me to input an audio file (.wav .mp3...) and output the text of the audio file.

Does such software exist? I have only found software that converts (live) voice to text, but not audio files to text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any that you can download, but I can make a clunky suggestion.

Google has built such a software, I know that they use it in YouTube and Google Voice.

It's [not very good](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/whatever-happened-to-voice-recognition.html), but you can call your Google Voice account, let the answering service pick up, and play the audio while your voicemail is recorded.

You'll get a transcription of the voicemail in your email.

I only suggest this because you don't have to train Google's engine.

Comment: Creative! Never thought of doing that.

Comment: In french it (still) doesn't really work. It catch maybe 20 to 30%, which is impressive, but unfortunately not really functional.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question specifically, but what I'd do in your situation is to distribute it as a Amazon Mechanical Turk job. You'll probably get the best results and pay the fewest dollars this way.

Comment: Cool. Never knew Amazon has provides a crowd searching service.

Answer (score 1):

eMicrophones makes a commercial product called [Windows Speech Recognition Toolkit](http://emicrophones.com/p-3033-wsrtoolkit-v2.aspx) that adds a lot of goodies to Windows Speech Recognition, including the ability to transcribe *.WAV files (provided they are from you, ie a recording as if you were speaking, not arbitrary voice). From the feature list:

> *Transcription* reads .WAV files from a digital recorder and transcribes it to text. This is meant to be used by the person who has a personal user profile and dictates as they would in front of the computer using good enunciation and punctuation. It is not meant to transcribe multiple voices from a meeting.

Answer (score 1):

You can add VOICENOTE software (free) to google voice.  That converts talk to text.  Then simply play the voice recording on your speaker directly into the microphone into VOICENOTE.

I plan to use VOICENOTE to transcribe my written notes into text and save in MS Word.  Then when I save a document, Windows can search for my handwritten notes on the computer.  Otherwise, the handwritten notes can only be saved as a picture.  Only the titles are searchaable and you can't find the document words for your search.

Answer (score 0):

There's a software project called 'fanscribe' that breaks up a recording and breaks it up into pieces, distributing them to interested people who can transcribe a portion of it.

https://github.com/fanscribed/fanscribed/blob/master/README.rst